# How to remove android title bar?

Tags: android

i have a question. i would like remove the title bar from android.
i use the java code : (before setcontentview)

[image]

to remove title bar :

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

to full screen:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

manifest.xml :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

What else do I need to do?

Comment: i know . i could not now

Comment: Could you be more specific about what the mentioned "title bar" is? Do you mean the ActionBar/Toolbar in activity or is it some kind of dialog, eg. AlertDialog?

Comment: o sorry. its action bar

Comment: have you tried `getSupportActionBar().hide()` in your activity?

Comment: i would suggest you to change your theme to `<style name="YourTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`. You won't have toolbar now

Comment: @johndoe thank you so much :)